# AngularJS views/regions

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and I have, I think, an architectural question.

If I want to **start** developing an application, let's say, like youtube, how do I organize the page in "regions" (like Marionette)? I mean: top-navbar, search box, side menu, main video, comments, etc.

Should those regions be wrapped in directives?

`<div top-navbar></div>`
`<div main-video="link_to_video"></div>`
etc...

Or controllers?
`<div ng-controller="top-navbar"></div>` 
etc...

Or nothing? Just throw 'em all under an `app-controller` for example.

I've also seen `ng-include` but I'm not sure it should be used here. Anyway, just a question about organization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely don't need directives for this, but, depending on complexity of each part, you might later learn that you would probably benefit from having each block inside it's own directive.

Since you're new to AngularJS I'd suggest you start with having each block associated with it's own controller. When need comes to communicate between the blocks you may make use of inheritance, shared services, or event broadcasts. In the process you'll gradually discover which blocks may require directive logic.

It's perfectly OK to use ng-include to load the view for each block. Otherwise (unless you're using directives) your main view would soon become quite heavy and hard to work with.

You might also want to take a look at some of the existing *seed* projects, to get a better picture of how these view/regions might be laid out.

1. [Angular App](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app)
2. [ng-boilerplate](http://joshdmiller.github.com/ng-boilerplate/#/home)

Answer (score 1):

If they are "almost indipendent GUI regions" I think would be better to use different modules (this would help you testing and debugging).

If they are related to each other I think using different controllers would be the best solution